# C# File GetAccessControl - 'File' does not contain a definition for 'GetAccessControl'

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the creator of a file, using C#. I've found multiple solutions which are using:

```
string user = File.GetAccessControl("").GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

But when I use this, the compiler throws: 'File' does not contain a definition for 'GetAccessControl'. I am using the includes:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
```

Any solutions to the problem? Or some other recommendations to get the file creator?

I am using Windows Forms, C# and .net 5

Comment: `File.GetAccessControl` is a framework method, try `FileSystemAclExtensions.GetAccessControl`

Comment: @TheGeneral I stand corrected.  Were these extensions in the original release?  Because I remember hitting the same issue when I ported.  Never saw them.

Comment: @Joe not sure tbh. I can see why they would likely refactor the file system class in core for a few reasons, though I am not sure of what the native BCL support is or was or whether this was a nuget only

Comment: Just came across the same problem. Seems like they definitely exist in the latest .NET framework release: [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0). The link to the Microsoft documentation contains "viewFallbackFrom" which redirects me to this page when I try to get the documentation for `GetAccessControl` for a .NET core framework. But then these methods don't seem to be available in .NET core. Odd.